# react Object.entries and map bug (one more entry than expected)

Tags: reactjs

I have this table in react:

```
<div className="table-responsive">
      <table className={classTable && classTable}>
        <thead className={classThead && classThead}>
          <tr className={`${tdClasses} border-r border-gray-200`}>
            {Object.entries(data[0]).map(([key, value]) => (
              <th className={`${tdClasses} text-left`} key={value}>
                {key}
              </th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item, index) => (
            <tr className={index % 2 ? evenClasses : oddClasses} key={index}>
              {Object.entries(item).map(([key, value]) => (
                <td
                  className={`${tdClasses} border-r border-gray-200`}
                  key={key}
                >
                  {key !== "year"
                    ? addSpaceSeparatorToNumber(Math.round(value))
                    : Math.round(value)}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

The data is composed of several objects of this form, this is data[0]:

```
 { year: 2021, conso_kwh_electrique: "161.48", conso_kwh_energie_primaire: "416.62", conso_kwh_m2_energie_primaire: "3.47", emission_ges: "11.95", perc: "" }
```

It usually works well except for one of the projects named CTTC in my web app.

The data object is correct but it gives me an html table with one more entry than expected.
So i think either the Object.entries either the map functions are doing something wrong.

The code that is not working well is:

```
{Object.entries(data[0]).map(([key, value]) => (
  <th className={`${tdClasses} text-left`} key={value}>
    {key}
  </th>
))}
```

How could I replace this piece of code with something similar that will not provoke a bug in adding one more entry than needed?

Comment: What is `data[0]`? That object you have in your question?? Anyway. Object.entries and map doesn't have a bug!

Comment: Should the `key={value}` be `key={key}` to make sure it is unique ?

Comment: It uses whatever data is there. If the data isn't right the output isn't right. We can't see the data, so we can't debug the data or the generated DOM.

Comment: If you start programming please learn this one thing that will save you a lot of time: the chances that the bug is in your code/data instead of in the common code of javascript is for all intents and purposes 100%

Comment: i have edited so you see what is data[0]. If object.entries and map are not in question, is there a possibility the resulting javascript table is interpreted incorrectly when rendering to html table?